# Sources for Aircraft Glide Ratio

Tags: aerodynamics, commercial-aviation, glide-ratio, literature-recommendation

I would like to gather data on the best glide ratio of different commercial aircraft. Unfortunately, it has proven non-trivial to obtain data aside from a few lucky examples.

[Eurocontrol's BADA](https://www.eurocontrol.int/news/bada-atms-most-comprehensive-aircraft-performance-model-just-got-even-better) gives $c_L$ and $c_d$, which could be used to compute L/D. Unfortunately, their license explicitly prohibits comparison of different aircraft types. The open-source alternative [OpenAP](https://openap.dev/) research project only contains data on a small number of aircraft and seems to be off in some cases (best glide ratio of a Cessna Citation II ~6).

Are [L/D curves or glide polars](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/3610/28511) available for commercial aircraft? Which is the best way to obtain data both for historical aircraft and current models?

I'm aware of the answers to the following questions:

- ["How does the Boeing 787 Dreamliner's glide ratio compare to other airliners?"](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/a/13975/), gives two good examples
- ["Where can I find glide ratios for commercial aircraft?"](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/a/33793/), gives no examples or sources
- ["How to calculate the Glide Ratio from Drag & Lift?"](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/14562), gives information on $c_{l/d}$
- ["How far can airplanes glide?"](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/a/3001/), gives only a general overview

the table on the [Wikipedia page on Gliding Flight](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gliding_flight#Examples) and a few prominent forum posts:

[Forum post](https://www.condorsoaring.com/forums/viewtopic.php?p=99347&sid=638abba0855e17095f2c922ff5c0ac60#p99347) (condorsoaring.com), no source provided

| Aircraft Model | Glide Ratio |
| --- | --- |
| Boeing B707-320 | 19.4 |
| Boeing 767-200 | 19.0 |
| Douglas DC-8 | 17.9 |
| Boeing 747-100 | 17.7 |
| Douglas DC-10 | 17.7 |
| Airbus A320 | 17.0 |
| Lockeed Tristar L1011 | 17.0 |
| Douglas DC-9 (1966) | 16.5 |
| Boeing B727-200 | 16.4 |
| Douglas DC-3 | 14.7 |

[Forum post](https://www.pprune.org/tech-log/537633-glide-ratio.html#post8432250) (pprune.org), estimates etc.

| Aircraft Model | Glide Ratio |
| --- | --- |
| B767-200 | 17.9 |
| B727 | ~17 |
| B757-200W | ~19.5 |
| B737-800W | ~19.5 |
| B777-200 | ~19 |
| B787-8 | 21-22 |

Answer (score 1):

Your table looks at least partially wrong. A Boeing 707-320 never achieved an L/D of 19.4.

If you have more reliable figures for fuel consumption, engine efficiency and range, you can use the Breguet Range Equation to determine L/D. See [this answer](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/88826/how-can-my-cd0-estimation-be-improved/88833#88833) for an application.